# App Protector type of app

Tags: android, logging

I'm writing an app similar to app protector - it prompts the user to authenticate himself when a protected app is launched. Since Android doesn't provide a way to use BroadcastReceiver on explicit intents, I'm detecting app launches by monitoring logcat. For most apps, I'm listening for something like "Starting activity..." and then throwing an intent to my own authentication activity.

However, there seems to be a loophole in this when a protected app A is launched via another App B. App A is only launched once(and hence will only have one "Starting activity..." entry in logcat, and if I switch to App B from my activity, it will re-route to App A, and this time, I won't be able to detect it since logcat doesn't show its launch.

An example would be package installer being a protected app, and a file manager launching package installer upon tapping an apk file. While my authentication activity is called up the first time, if I switch to the file manager again, it will automatically display package installer, and this time my app doesn't detect it.

I've tried a few app protector apps such as App Protector Lite and Smart App Protector, and they don't seem to have this problem. They have similar permissions as well - GET_TASKS, READ_LOGS, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, and SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. Does anyone know what can be done to solve my problem?

Thanks.